# SQL Server adding constraints

Tags: sql-server, constraints

I have the following two tables

```
Create table Exam
(
    coursecode nvarchar(6) Not Null Constraint Pk_courseCode Primary Key (coursecode),
    [examiner-name] [varchar](25) ,
    [date] date not null,
    slot varchar(2),

)

Alter table Exam with check 
  add constraint [coursecode_ck_validity] check ((coursecode like '[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9]'))

Alter table Exam with check 
  add constraint [date_ck_validity] check  (Month([date]) = 5 or Month([date]) = 11)

Alter table Exam with check 
  add constraint [slot_ck_validity] check (slot in ('AM', 'PM'))
```

And this table `Student`

```
Create table Student
(
    [script-id] int identity(1,1) not null Constraint [PK_Student] Primary key ([script-id]),
    [student-id] char(8) not null,
    [course-code] nvarchar(6) Not Null constraint [FK_Student] foreign key([course-code]) references Exam ([course-code]),
    [seat-no] int not null constraint [seatno_ck_validity] check ([seat-no] between 1 and 3000 )

)
```

And to add on to the above statements I have additional constraints that I have to apply, but not sure how to to apply these constraints

Constraints

- Delete to course-code is disallowed and update to course-code is cascaded.
- Minimum cardinality between Exam and Student is M:O.

Thanks

Comment: Cascading an update to is almost always a bad idea. Better to give the exam table another column of type `int` and make that the primary key.

Comment: But that is the requirement set out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Delete to course-code is disallowed and update to course-code is cascaded

Do you mean *Delete to `Exam` is disallowed*? If so, do not `grant` (or actively `deny`) `Delete` on the `Exam` table.

> update to the course-code is cascaded

Use [Cascading Referential Integrity Constraints](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186973.aspx):

```
Create table Student
(
    -- ...
    [course-code] nvarchar(6) Not Null 
        Constraint [FK_Student] foreign key([course-code]) 
        References Exam ([course-code]) /***/ On Update Cascade /***/
    -- ...
)
```

... and your second condition...

> Minimum cardinality between Exam and Student is M:O.

I am not sure what issue you are attempting to solve with this condition. Your `Not Null` and `Foreign Key` constraint on `Student.course-code` should be all that is needed.

As an aside, be sure to have a consistent naming convention; specifically, compare `Exam.coursecode` and `Student.course-code`. Also, underscores are much more prevalent than hyphens in object names in the professional SQL world.